# Do Idioms such as “all the more” function as adjectives or adverbs?

Tags: idioms

> All the more reason to value these beautiful little creatures and their habitat, right? (From TOEFL)

In the sentence above, I think "all the more" is functioning as an adjective. In Merriam-Webster dictionary, this expression is categorized as an idiom without indicating whether it is an adjective or adverb. For the example given by Webster, "The fact that they'd written the play themselves made it all the more impressive", I feel like "all the more" is used as an adverb modifying adjective impressive.

So, in effect, what grammatical part does the idiom "all the more" play?

Comment: *All the more reason to value these beautiful little creatures and their habitat, right?* is part of the exam because it is not a sentence and this tests the student's ability in English. However, you are asking about a phrase, and that phrase needs to be set in a sentence: Can you do that please? (The grammar of "all the more" is quite strange.)

Comment: It's certainly an idiom, and it's modifying "reason".

Comment: But it doesn't function as an adjective or an adverb, so the answer is actually No. It is a quantifier, so it functions as a determiner, which is neither an adjective nor an adverb. If you think those are the only two alternatives, you're not up to speed yet on parts of speech.

Comment: @John Lawler. Thanks for your answer! But I do not think the function as a determiner rings true for the example provided by Webster, "The fact that they'd written the play themselves made it all the more impressive." Or because this idiom has two parts of speech?

Comment: Quantifiers can modify verb phrases as well as noun phrases. [Quantifier-float](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20quantifier%20float) , for instance, describes the link with the quantifier _all_  between _All the dogs have eaten their bones_ (where the quantifier looks like an adjective, modifying a noun phrase) and _The dogs have all eaten their bones_ (where it acts like an adverb, nestled right after the first auxiliary verb). The sentences mean the same thing, which is one reason why we need some different parts of speech. Some things have been discovered since 600.

Comment: Oh, and incidentally, dictionaries are not where you look up parts of speech. They are determined by grammars, not dictionaries. All a dictionary can do is list some of the meanings and uses of the word that have been noticed repeatedly in print. For anything having to do with grammar, that's not much, especially since any English word can be used as any open-category part of speech: noun, verb, adjective, adverb. Without inflection, one uses more "particles" that don't fit Latin definitions.